# What is the difference between date +%F and date '+%F' in UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to know the difference between date +%F and date '+%F' in UNIX. I am getting same result for both. When i am using the later one in my shell program i am not getting the expected output while the first one gives me the expected output.
Eg:

```
    DATE=$(date '+%F')
    echo $DATE
    2018-03-18

    DATE=$(date +%F)
    echo $DATE
    2018-03-18
```

the problem is when i am using it inside a for loop

```
    #!/bin/bash
    PICTURES=$(ls /root/Desktop/images | grep jpeg)
    DATE=$(date '+%F')
    for PICTURE in $PICTURES
    do
    echo "Renaming ${PICTURE} as ${DATE}-${PICTURE}"
    done
```

Error:
 line 7: Unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
 line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: You didn't even post 10 lines of code.

Comment: `for PICTURE in $PICTURES`, on the other hand, is buggy -- you'll have a bad time for any filename containing spaces. See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Use `date=$(date +%F); for picture in /root/Desktop/images/*jpeg*; do echo "Renaming ${picture} as ${date}-${picture}"; done`, or such.

Comment: The quoting in the argument to `date` certainly doesn't have anything to do with your unexpected EOF error, anyhow.

Comment: Run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here -- and log the invocation, to see what it actually does when it's run, by starting it with `bash -x yourscript`.

Comment: The above is a sample code. I just want to know the difference. If you know that please advise

Comment: @EbisonJ If you just want to know the difference between `date +%F` and `date '+%F'`, why did you post an error message (that doesn't appear to come from the code you posted right above the message or have anything to do with the `date` call, which happens well before line 7)?

Comment: @Daniel H then why date '+%F' is giving error and date +%F gives the output

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thank you for your information. It was relay helpful.

Comment: @EbisonJ, it's hard to believe that that *is* the only difference between the working and broken versions, since both those forms are valid. If you want us to believe that, we need code we can run without modifications to get the exact error ourselves; see the [mcve] definition in the Help Center, describing how to build such an example.

Comment: @EbisonJ If that is the only difference, I'd double check that both of those really are apostrophes and that you didn't get a smart quote or mismatched single and double quotes somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in date format. Your problem is the way you parse the files. You get an error and you assume that the error is related to date command. But it is not. Try this code to convience your self:

```
$ DATE=$(date +%F);for i in $(seq 1 5);do echo "$DATE-$i";done
2018-03-17-1
2018-03-17-2
2018-03-17-3
2018-03-17-4
2018-03-17-5

$ DATE=$(date '+%F');for i in $(seq 1 5);do echo "$DATE-$i";done
2018-03-17-1
2018-03-17-2
2018-03-17-3
2018-03-17-4
2018-03-17-5
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason to quote the arguments of `date` is to allow for string expansion. For example, even though the next two commands produce same output:

```
date '+%F'
date  +%F
```

the following two commands do not:

```
date 'date: +%F hour: %H'
date  date: +%F hour: %H
```